# I have two tables with composite primary key, I want the following relevant inner join using jpa

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa

DB table details:

EmployeeDetail :

- PK is made up of `employeeId` and `team`, other columns are `lname`, `fname`

EmployeePerformance:

- PK is made up of `employeeId` and `employeeId`, `month`, other columns are `grade`

How should I write an entity class (persistence) for above table details?

I have two persistence classes with both having embedded id

```
@Entity
public class EmployeePerformance  {

  @EmbeddedId
  private EmployeePerformancePK emplPerfPK;

  private String grade;
}


@Embeddable
public class EmployeePerformancePK   {

  private int employeeId;
  private String month;
}


@Entity
public class EmployeeDetail  {

  @EmbeddedId
  private EmployeeDetailPK emplPerfPK;

  private String lname;
  private String fname;

}


@Embeddable
public class EmployeeDetailPK   {

  private int employeeId;
  private String team;

}
```

using JPA concept

I want to execute this query in spring web service

```
SELECT 
FROM EmployeeDetail
INNER JOIN EmployeePerformance ON EmployeeDetail.employeeId = EmployeePerformance.employeeId 
WHERE EmployeePerformance.grade = "B";
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a composite Id class in jpa and there a way to make the query in jpa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45261729/create-a-composite-id-class-in-jpa-and-there-a-way-to-make-the-query-in-jpa)